# Why am I getting syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in this template?

Tags: page-template

I'm trying to echo a form, when the user is logged in, I get this in the browser when I upload the code:

`syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in`

My code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Customers
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php if (is_user_logged_in()):

echo '<form type="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm"> ';

echo '<label for="name">Name:</label>';
echo'<input name="name" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="email">Email:</label>';
echo'<input name="email" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="phone">Phone:</label>';
echo'<input name="phone" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="address">Address:</label>';
echo'<input name="address" type="text" />';

echo'<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCustomer"/>';
echo'<input type="submit">';
echo'</form>';
echo'<br/><br/>';
echo'<div id="feedback"></div>';
echo '<br/><br/>';

else:
echo 'Sorry, only registered users can view this information';
?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `<?php endif; ?>`

```
[...]

else:
echo 'Sorry, only registered users can view this information';

endif;

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to end the `if` statement. this should work:

```
   <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php if (is_user_logged_in()):

echo '<form type="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm"> ';

echo '<label for="name">Name:</label>';
echo'<input name="name" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="email">Email:</label>';
echo'<input name="email" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="phone">Phone:</label>';
echo'<input name="phone" type="text" />';

echo'<label for="address">Address:</label>';
echo'<input name="address" type="text" />';

echo'<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCustomer"/>';
echo'<input type="submit">';
echo'</form>';
echo'<br/><br/>';
echo'<div id="feedback"></div>';
echo '<br/><br/>';

else:
echo 'Sorry, only registered users can view this information';
?>

            <?php  endif;?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```